# Pytest: deleting files created by the tested function

Tags: python, pickle, pytest

I am testing a function that, as part of its execution, pickles objects. After the test, I want to delete the pickle files.

If it is the test itself that saves files, `pytest`’s “tmpdir” fixture seems like the solution. However, with the function undergoing testing being the creator of saved files, and not the test, I’m not sure what the proper way to clean up the files after the test is.

In this case, the files are being saved in the “tests” directory that contains the tests being run. The only option I can think of is to delete all *.pkl pickle files from the test directory after each test. I am wondering if I am missing a more elegant solution that pytest may provide.

What is the standard way of cleaning up any files that are generated as a side effect of a function being tested with `pytest`?

Comment: So, the question would be, why is the function under test saving files into the `tests` directory? I would suggest either fixing the code under test, or mocking or otherwise changing its environment to put the created files into a specific place.

Comment: I have a computationally-intensiive series of matrix operations required by a function. The function can be faster if a library of partial numpy solutions is generated and pickled. Then, every time the computation is called, the function either loads the previously computed partial solutions, or generates them.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was not clear.  I don't care why you are pickling.  My question is why you are pickling to that specific directory?

Comment: It pickles to the directory you’re calling it from. The ultimate goal is to create a pip-installable library of functions, where the package includes these partial solutions in the same directory as the library functions. I am a PyPI n00b, so I may be totally off my rocker, but the idea is that I will generate partial solutions for the most common use cases by running a script within the library folder prior to packaging. When the function fails to discover a “canned” partial solutions, it generates and pickles one.

Comment: If that is the case, then the test case can simply do a `chdir()` before calling the function, to have the function put the files into the chdir'ed directory.  Right?

Comment: I suppose, but during the testing phase these files still need to be deleted regardless of their location. Currently I just want them to go *poof* after the test, regardless of location. In production, I suppose I would want them to go to the right place and persist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can monkeypatch file opening function and check whether a new file is written. Collect new files in a list. Afterwards, go through the list and remove the files. Example:

```
# spam.py
import pathlib
import numpy

def plain_write():
    with open('spam.1', 'w') as f:
        f.write('eggs')


def pathlib_write():
    with pathlib.Path('spam.2').open('w') as f:
        f.write('eggs')


def pathlib_write_text():
    pathlib.Path('spam.3').write_text('eggs')


def pathlib_write_bytes():
    pathlib.Path('spam.3').write_bytes(b'eggs')


def numpy_save():
    numpy.save('spam.4', numpy.zeros([10, 10]))

def numpy_savetxt():
    numpy.savetxt('spam.5', numpy.zeros([10, 10]))
```

#### tests

Depending on what functions you test, monkeypatching `builtins.open` may not be enough: for example, to cleanup files written with `pathlib`, you need to additionally monkeypatch `io.open`.

```
import builtins
import io
import os
import pytest
import spam


def patch_open(open_func, files):
    def open_patched(path, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, 
                    errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True,
                    opener=None):
        if 'w' in mode and not os.path.isfile(path):
            files.append(path)
        return open_func(path, mode=mode, buffering=buffering, 
                         encoding=encoding, errors=errors,
                         newline=newline, closefd=closefd, 
                         opener=opener)
    return open_patched


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def cleanup_files(monkeypatch):
    files = []
    monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, 'open', patch_open(builtins.open, files))
    monkeypatch.setattr(io, 'open', patch_open(io.open, files))
    yield
    for file in files:
        os.remove(file)


def test_plain_write():
    assert spam.plain_write() is None


def test_pathlib_write():
    assert spam.pathlib_write() is None


def test_pathlib_write_text():
    assert spam.pathlib_write_text() is None


def test_pathlib_write_bytes():
    assert spam.pathlib_write_bytes() is None


def test_numpy_save():
    assert spam.numpy_save() is None


def test_numpy_savetxt():
    assert spam.numpy_savetxt() is None
```