# Is there an in-built way to clean up figure files after using matplotlib testing check_figures_equal decorator?

Tags: python, matplotlib, testing, pytest

Using the example from the `matplotlib.testing` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/testing_api.html#matplotlib.testing.decorators.check_figures_equal), if this file:

```py
@check_figures_equal()
def test_plot(fig_test, fig_ref):
    fig_test.subplots().plot([1, 3, 5])
    fig_ref.subplots().plot([0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 5])
```

is in some directory `tests/functional/test_plotting.py`, then after running this test (via `pytest`) it creates files of the form:

```
test_plot[png].png
test_plot[png]-expected.png
# etc...
```

in a directory `result_images/test_plotting`.

I understand that it needs these files for doing the image comparisons, but I was wondering if there's some option or additional fixture that can be applied to remove these files when the test is complete (rather than writing a custom clean-up fixture of some sort). It seems quite odd that it keeps them stored as permanent files when I don't see a need for these to be kept around.

Comment: there is no built-in way to do this it seems, you will need to create a cleanup method yourself. maybe within a hook or something when the session finishes

Comment: That's a shame. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51742499/) seems to work quite well, with some modifications, for this purpose anyway.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question if it solves the problem, that way future readers will have an answer to look at.